# angular.js Updating model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If you try the jsfiddle link below, type something in the textbox labeled "Tag Name" and hit the update button. Notice the console.log > ParmAndValue.Value is set to what you typed in, as expected. But now type something else in and hit update again. This time is doesn't update the model? How come?

https://jsfiddle.net/8evuoqLz/11/

```
<body ng-app="eApp">
<div id="sms" ng-controller="smsController" ng-cloak>
  <ul id="paramsList" class="ulDynamic">
    <li ng-repeat="actionParam in actions.SmsResponseActionParmAndValue" id="li_{{actionParam.Order}}">
      <div ng-repeat="param in actionParam.ParmAndValue">
        <label ng-bind="param.ParmName"></label>
        <input ng-model="param.Value" type="{{param.SmsInputType}}" />
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
<br>
```

javascript

```
var app = angular.module('eApp', []);
  app.controller('smsController', function ($scope) {

  $scope.actions = {"SmsResponseActionParmAndValue":[{"Description":"Tag     User","Order":null,"ParmAndValue":[{"ParmId":9,"ParmName":"Tag Name","ParmType":"String","ParmVersion":"","Value":"","ValueId":null,"ValueVersion":"","ExtensionData":{},"Id":null,"Version":null}],"ExtensionData":{},"Id":10,"Version":"AAAAAAp96lg="}],"ExtensionData":{},"Id":null,"Version":null};

  $scope.updateDetails = function () {
    console.log("update");
    console.log($scope.actions.SmsResponseActionParmAndValue);
  };
});
```

Comment: It only works the first time... type something in and hit update and notice the Value property. It's set the first time, now type another word in and hit the update button and the Value does not update. You have to look in the Console window to tell...

Comment: It appears to be updating okay in your fiddle.

Comment: Not in Firefox? Type one in the textbox hit update. In the console.log window notice ParmAndValue.Value is set to one. That works. Now type two in the textbox hit update. In the console.log window notice ParmAndValue.Value is still set to one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the key `SmsInputType` from `ParmAndValue`. Now each time the `Value` gets updated.

```
"ParmAndValue": [{
    "ParmId": 9,
    "ParmName": "Tag Name",
    "ParmType": "String",
    "ParmVersion": "",
    "Value": "",
    "ValueId": null,
    "ValueVersion": "",
    "ExtensionData": {},
    "Id": null,
    "Version": null,
    "SmsInputType": "text" //<---- This one
  }],
```

Here is the full code:

```
var app = angular.module('eApp', []);
//Controller
app.controller('smsController', function($scope) {

  $scope.actions = {
    "SmsResponseActionParmAndValue": [{
      "Description": "Tag User",
      "Order": null,
      "ParmAndValue": [{
        "ParmId": 9,
        "ParmName": "Tag Name",
        "ParmType": "String",
        "ParmVersion": "",
        "Value": "",
        "ValueId": null,
        "ValueVersion": "",
        "ExtensionData": {},
        "Id": null,
        "Version": null,
        "SmsInputType": "text"
      }],
      "ExtensionData": {},
      "Id": 10,
      "Version": "AAAAAAp96lg="
    }],
    "ExtensionData": {},
    "Id": null,
    "Version": null
  };

  $scope.updateDetails = function() {
    console.log("update");
    console.log($scope.actions.SmsResponseActionParmAndValue[0].ParmAndValue[0].Value);
    console.log($scope.actions.SmsResponseActionParmAndValue);
  };
});
```

Comment: I added that but still doesn't update Value in ParmAndValue for me. Firefox

Comment: Did you hit "Play" again? I'm using firefox too and it's working fine. I'm going to update my answer to show the full code, however i changed only the SmsInputType and i formatted the code. You may consider to clean browser cache.

Comment: Crazy, so the console.log all the way to the Value, looks correct. But the console.log of the object and the traversing it doesn't? That's odd: https://jsfiddle.net/8evuoqLz/15/

Comment: is it just a bug in Firebug?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me as well.

Possible reason for your post:

1) weird behaviour of your browser.

2) looking at the wrong data in that "messy" structure.

```
console.log($scope.actions.SmsResponseActionParmAndValue[0].ParmAndValue[0].Value);
```

Comment: Well strange, when I do your above console.log it seems to show the updated value, but when you navigate the object it doesn't. See https://jsfiddle.net/8evuoqLz/14/

Comment: Works flawless for me. I assume you are using Firebug on Firefox, and got used to it´s (no more?) weird behaviour of updating old output with new values.

Comment: I think it's a bug in Firebug

Comment: Told you so! lvlup please? ;)

Answer (score 0):

It updates the model for me. I reviewed the code and it looks fine. Are you sure you are not looking at the previous object in the debug console instead of the new one?

Comment: I'm sure, make sure you hit update, then type something again and hit update and check the Value